# Android RecyclerView Navigation in Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to navigate to a fragment within a RecyclerView adapter, the reason being I have a list of items with buttons with different text and on click of each button depending on the text on the button, I want it to navigate to different fragments that correspond to that text. What is the best way to handle this navigation?

```
     class DummyAdapter(val context: Context, private var DummyList: ArrayList<DummyModel>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<DummyAdapter.DummyViewHolder>() {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int): DummyViewHolder {
            val dummyBinding: ListItemDummyBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.list_item_dummy,
                parent,
                false
            )
            return DummyViewHolder(dummyBinding)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return dummyList.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DummyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val item = dummyList[position]
            holder.bind(item)

            holder.dummyItemBinding.buttonDummy.setOnClickListener {
                if (holder.dummyItemBinding.buttonDummy.text == "Fragment 1") {

                    //The actual Navigation Logic to be added
                }
            }
            holder.dummyItemBinding.buttonDummy.setOnClickListener {
                if (holder.dummyItemBinding.buttonDummy.text == "Fragment 2") {

                    //The actual Navigation Logic to be added
                }

            }
        }

            inner class DummyViewHolder(var dummyItemBinding: ListItemDummyBinding) :
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder(dummyItemBinding.root) {
                private lateinit var dummyItem: DummyModel
                fun bind(dummyItem: DummyModel) {
                    this.dummyItem = dummyItem
                    dummyItemBinding.buttonDummy.text = dummyItem.button_text
                }
            }
   }
```

Comment: you have to use listeners inside on click events within adapter to handler navigation in main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

Pass callback to adapter

```
class DummyAdapter(
    val context: Context, 
    private var DummyList: ArrayList<DummyModel>,
    private val onButtonClickedListener: (buttonText: String) -> Unit
): RecyclerView.Adapter<DummyAdapter.DummyViewHolder>() {
// ...
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DummyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = dummyList[position]
    holder.bind(item)
    holder.dummyItemBinding.buttonDummy.setOnClickListener {
        val buttonText = holder.dummyItemBinding.buttonDummy.text
        onButtonClickedListener(buttonText)
    }
}
```

And when you create adapter put reference to function:

```
val adapter = DummyAdapter(context, dummyList, ::onDummyItemClicked)

fun onDummyItemClicked(buttonText: String) {
    when(buttonText) {
        "Fragment 1" -> goToFragment1()
        "Fragment 2" -> goToFragment2()
    }
}
```

Comment: this actually worked for me ,thank you very much  for the save